# Why is numeric_limits<int>::max() > numeric_limits<int>::infinity()?

Tags: c++, integer, numeric, limits, integral

I was reading [Setting an int to Infinity in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690567/setting-an-int-to-infinity-in-c). I understand that when one needs true infinity, one is supposed to use `numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`; I guess the rationale behind it is that usually integral types have no values designated for representing special states like *NaN*, *Inf*, etc. like IEEE 754 floats do (again C++ doesn't mandate neither - `int` & `float` used are left to the implementation); but still it's misleading that `max > infinity` for a given type. I'm trying to understand the rationale behind this call in the standard. If having `infinity` doesn't make sense for a type, then shouldn't it be disallowed instead of having a flag to be checked for its validity?

Comment: Are you sure that `numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity` is `true`? If it's not, then the standard doesn't require `infinity()` to be meaningful.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/has_infinity

Comment: Yep, like I mentioned in the question, one cannot represent infinity using an integer value because of its inherent nature, but still a Joe coder not knowing `has_infinity()` trying out the above line will shoot his foot nice and square; it seems unintuitive.

Comment: Most answers say the same thing mentioned in the question, but not the actual rationale; say why did the standards committee, instead of giving a `has_infinity()`, didn't opt for not defining `infinity()` for such types?

Comment: @legends2k: It is not `has_infinity()`, it is just `has_infinity`. It is not a function.

Comment: @legends2k: I agree with you. If this function doesn't return any meaningful value, then it should not exist, or at least require the implementation *to reject the code on using this function*. That is not that difficult. With the help of some metaprograming, the implementation could detect meaningless usage. But then I think such techniques was discovered later.

Comment: @Nawaz Oh yes, just noticed that has_infinity isn't a function, thanks! And yes again, one could've avoided it with SFINAE.

Comment: “Integral types are finite”, *as are* floating-point types—floats trade precision for range, and merely have additional special representations for positive and negative infinity, signed zero, and NaN.

Comment: @JonPurdy Agreed, fixed it in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The function `numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` makes sense for those `T` for which  `numeric_limits<T>::has_infinity` returns  `true`.

In case of `T=int`, it returns `false`. So that comparison doesn't make sense, because `numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` does not return any *meaningful* value to compare with.

Comment: In fact, the standard _requires_ non-meaningful values to be `0` or `false`.

Comment: Why are we even allowed to make comparisons that don't make sense? Why not fail at compile time if someone tries to use `numeric_limits<int>::infinity()`?

Answer (score 6):

If you read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) you will see a table showing infinity to be zero for integer types. That's because integer types in C++ can't, by definition, be infinite.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose, conversely, the standard *did* reserve some value to represent inifity, and that `numeric_limits<int>::infinity() > numeric_limits<int>::max()`. That means that there would be some value of `int` which is greater than `max()`, that is, some representable value of `int` is greater than the greatest representable value of int.

Clearly, whichever way the Standard specifies, some natural understanding is violated. Either `inifinity() <= max()`, or there exists x such that `int(x) > max()`. The Standard must choose which rule of nature to violate.

I believe they chose wisely.

Comment: There is a third option: require the implementation to reject the code which uses `numeric_limits<int>::infinity()`  - which is possible with a bit of metaprogramming.

Comment: @Robᵩ This seems to be right; although I'd say, like Nawaz suggested, this could've been avoided for types which don't have an infinity representation using SFINAE, but I guess these functions were defined earlier than meta-programming's advent.

Comment: Also this shows that the language projects what the machine does as is, which, in my opinion, isn't great because later suppose some novel machine's architecture does support infinity for integral types, then its `has_infinity` would be true, and hence it's the programmer who has to add another exception to his mental model. This is exactly what makes C++ expert-friendly and complex for the Joe coder.

Answer (score 0):

`numeric_limits<int>::infinity()` returns the representation of positive infinity, if available.

In case of integers, positive infinity does not exists:

```
cout << "int has infinity: " << numeric_limits<int>::has_infinity << endl;
```

prints

```
int has infinity: false
```