# What is the right way to declare integer INFINITY in C++?

Tags: c++

```
const int INFINITY = INT_MAX;
```

gives me the

> expected an identifier

error. Could you please tell what am I missing? I tried to include `<cmath>` but it did not help.

Comment: Use `<stdint.h>`  & `<limits.h>` from C, or `#include <cstdint>`

Comment: @Rachael Mark the answer as accepted, please.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `INFINITY` is either a [macro from the `<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY) header. This is expanded to an implementation-defined value by the preprocessor before the actual compilation. In the case of GCC (check with `g++ -E`), the expression `(__builtin_inff ())` takes the place of `INFINITY`, which clearly not a valid identifier.

A quick fix is to give your constant a different name, such that it is not reserved by the implementation (is not a name of a standard macro):

```
const int infinity = INT_MAX;
```

---

But, when it comes to the title of the question:

> What is the right way to declare the INFINITY in c++?

refer to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690567/setting-an-int-to-infinity-in-c) that suggests this C++ standard library equivalent:

```
#include <limits>

const int infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

<sup>Note that integers do not have reserved *infinity* (Inf), or *not a number* (NaN) and operations that result in a value out of `int`'s range will (still) overflow, as opposed to operations with IEEE floating-point numbers, which according to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588419/when-a-float-variable-goes-out-of-the-float-limits-what-happens), don't overflow and result in `Inf`.</sup>

Comment: _"`0x7f800000` being the hexadecimal representation"_ — this can't directly be an implementation of `INFINITY`: it's an `int` literal, which would require a `reinterpret_cast` to become a `float`. In GCC and Clang actual implementation is `(__builtin_inff ())`, while in MSVC it's `((float)(1e+300 * 1e+300))`.

Comment: @Ruslan Thank you for the correction and investigation.

Answer (score 1):

INT_MAX is the C way.
You should use the following in C++ :-

```
#include <limits>

int infinity = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

Comment: This doesn't even try to answer the question. It will fail the same way as the OP's version when renaming `infinity` back to `INFINITY`.

Comment: At least, it uses the C++ way, and not the C way. +1 for that.