# C++: Create integer vector of infinities

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, int

I'm working on an algorithm and I need to initialize the vector of ints:

`std::vector<int> subs(10)`

of fixed length with values:

```
{-inf, +inf, +inf …. }
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690567/setting-an-int-to-infinity-in-c) is where I read that it is possible to use `MAX_INT`, but it's not quiete correct because the elements of my vector are supposed to be greater than any possible int value.

I liked overrloading comparison operator method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690597/5411664), but how do you initialize the vector with `infinitytype` class objects if there are supposed to be an `int`?

Or maybe you know any better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: there is no infinity type for ints.

Comment: `int` is a type typically of size 32 bits. To the object of type `int`, you can therefore store any 0/1 combination of 32 bits. Each such combination is interpreted as a finite number. There is no option to store `inf` into integer.

Comment: If your vector elements may be greater than any possible `int` value, the they cannot be `int` values. It looks like you have an XY problem. Why do you need infinity vaues?

Comment: @n.m.`<=` of course

Comment: @GusevSlava If you need `<=` then `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`? If you need `<` then you can't do that with `int`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `<=` means "less than or equal to". Every int value is less than or equal to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that every input integer value has to be `<` than all elements of vector, except the first element.

Comment: An integer value you are looking for does not exist. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Will you be doing anything more then comparing `>` and `<` against `int`? You could extend @lisyarus idea by adding `operator=` and `operator int()` ect. and then you can use it as if it was an int.

Comment: Your vector contains int values. By definition, an int value cannot be greater than the greatest possible int value. Same for floats: even `+inf` is not larger than `+inf`.

Comment: "I mean that every input integer value has to be < than all elements of vector, except the first element" Would a `std::set<int, std::greater<>>` be the collection you are after? I.e. a collection of `int` values in descending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution depends on the assumptions your algorithm (or the implementation of your algorithm) has:

- You could increase the element size beyond int (e.g. if your `sizeof(int)` is 4, use `int64_t`), and initialize to `(int64_t) 1 + std::numeric_limits<int>:max()` (and similarly for the negative values). But perhaps your algorithm assumes that you can't "exceed infinity" by adding on multiplying by positive numbers?
- You could use an [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/) like other answers suggest, selecting between an int and infinity; but perhaps your algorithm assumes your elements behave like numbers?
- You could use a ratio-based "number" class, ensuring it will not get non-integral values except infinity.
- You could have your algorithm special-case the maximum and minimum integers
- You could use `float`s or `double`s which support -/+ infinity, and restrict them to integrality.
- etc.

So, again, it really just depends and there's no one-size-fits-all solution.

Answer (score 1):

AS already said in the comments, you can't have an infinity value stored in `int`: all values of this type are well-defined and *finite*.

If you are ok with a vector of *something* working as an infinite for ints, then consider using a type like this:

```
struct infinite
{ };

bool operator < (int, infinite)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the question - there's no `-inf`. Your `infinite` class will need at least a `bool negative`, and it needs to be taken into account when comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variant (for example, [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/variant.html)) which supports double dispatching, which stores either an `int` or an `infinitytype` (which should store the sign of the infinity, for example in a bool), then implement the comparison operators through a visitor.

But I think it would be simpler if you simply used a `double` instead of `int`, and whenever you take out a value that is not infinity, convert it to int. If performance is not that great of an issue, then it will work fine (probably still faster than a variant). If you need great performance, then just use `MAX_INT` and be done with it.

Comment: Variants are now standard C++ - as of C++17: [`std::variant`](en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/).

Comment: @einpoklum Do standard variants support double dispatching?

Answer (score 0):

You are already aware of the idea of an "infinite" type, but that implementation could *only* contain infinite values. There's another related idea:

```
struct extended_int {
  enum {NEGINF, FINITE, POSINF} type;
  int finiteValue; // Only meaningful when type==FINITE

  bool operator<(extended_int rhs) {
    if (this->type==POSINF) return false;
    if (rhs.type==NEGINF) return false;
    if (this->type==FINITE && rhs.type==POSINF) return false;
    if (this->type==NEGINF && rhs.type==FINITE) return false;
    assert(this->type==FINITE && rhs.type==FINITE);
    return this->finiteValue < rhs.finiteValue)
  }

  // Implicitly converting ctor
  constexpr extended_int(int value) : type(FINITE), finiteValue(value) { }
  // And the two infinities
  static constexpr extended_int posinf;
  static constexpr extended_int neginf;
}
```

You now have `extended_int(5) < extended_int(6)` but also `extended_int(5) < extended_int::posinf`